# How do you print within a for loop without starting a new line?

Tags: for-loop, printing, newline, indentation, pascals-triangle

I have written some code for a program which will find Pascal's triangle. However, the formatting is not coming out as I would have hoped. My code is as follows:
    def factorial(n):
        """Calculate a factorial"""
        p = 1
        for i in range(1, n+1):
            p = p * i
        return p

```
def binomial(n, k):
    """Calculate n choose k"""
    y = int(factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*factorial(n-k)))
    return y

a = int(input("How many rows of Pascal's triangle do you want?: "))
for j in range(a):
    for i in range(j + 1):
        n = (a-1)-j
        print(" "*n, binomial(j, i), end=" ")
    print("")
```

Thanks to the for loop doing the `" "*n`bit before every `i in range(j+1)`, instead of getting a nice pascal's triangle:

```
     1
    1 1
   1 2 1
  1 3 3 1
 1 4 6 4 1
```

I get:

```
     1 
    1     1 
   1    2    1 
  1   3   3   1 
 1  4  6  4  1
```

Is there anything I can do to help with this formatting error? I tried putting the `n = (a-1)-j` and `print(" "*n)` bit outside the `for i in range(j+1)` and inside just the `for j in range(a)`, to see if this would only indent the text once, but this created a new line. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Yet again I post after struggling for hours only to find the answer within minutes...

Here I fixed the problem of the recurring spacing by adding an `if` command into the code like this:

```
def factorial(n):
    """Calculate a factorial"""
    p = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        p = p * i
    return p

def binomial(n, k):
    """Calculate n choose k"""
    y = int(factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*factorial(n-k)))
return y

a = int(input("How many rows of Pascal's triangle do you want?: "))
for j in range(a):
    for i in range(j + 1):
        if i == 0:
            n = (a-1)-j
            print(" "*n, binomial(j, i), end=" ")
        else:
            print(binomial(j, i), end=" ")
    print("")
```

This ensured that the initial indentation by `(a-1)-j` only happened for the first incidence of the for loop.